# didUpdateLocations being called repeatedly in Xcode simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

My Xcode swift project seems to be calling the CLLocationManager didUpdateLocations over and over and over in an infinite loop and I can't seem to make it stop. Why is it doing this?! I'm certainly not invoking it programmatically, if that's even possible. Is it something to do with the simulator and the fake location being used? Would it not behave this way if I tested it on a real device? That seems my only potential solution but I can't find anything that will confirm this.

Comment: did you try to stop the updates in the delegate method?

Comment: manager.stopUpdatingLocation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Simulator` if you use `CLLocationManager` then its `delegate` calling frequently in real device it will work fine.

Try with following `Selected Location` may be it will be helpful to you.

You can use following option of `location` in `Simulator`

Debug -> Location -> City Bicycle Ride OR

Debug -> Location -> City Run